# Selenium crashes at GULP Protractor test

Tags: firefox, selenium, gulp, protractor

My Selenium server keeps crashing after performing a GULP protractor test. I can only run tests using directconnect option but I want to use PhatomJS wich does not support this. I think it crashes at the point it tries to create a new session (firefox in this case). Is there anything that can be done about this?

My error log from Selenium:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001c48df09b, pid=5708, tid=8412
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b26) (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000001c48df09b
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000009d8a000):  JavaThread "Session bda2f461-2645-43bb-9a80-4786c39faef1 processing inside browser" [_thread_in_native, id=8412, stack(0x000000000bf70000,0x000000000c070000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x00000001c48df09b

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000009d8a1f8, RCX=0x0000000000990ff0, RDX=0x000000000c06d7c8
RSP=0x000000000c06d7d0, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x0000000009f9ee40
R8 =0x000000018006eb38, R9 =0x0000000000008000, R10=0x00000000d73e75d8, R11=0x000000005eef0d50
R12=0x0000000000000001, R13=0x000000000b35a180, R14=0x000000000c06d9d8, R15=0x0000000000000002
RIP=0x00000001c48df09b, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000c06d7d0)
0x000000000c06d7d0:   0000000009f9ee40 000000000c060018
0x000000000c06d7e0:   fffffffffffffffe 000000000c06d838
0x000000000c06d7f0:   0000000009d8a1f8 000000018002dbf2
0x000000000c06d800:   000000018006eac0 0000000000990ff0
0x000000000c06d810:   000000000a3b6d10 000000000a3b6d10
0x000000000c06d820:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000c06d830:   fffffffffffffffe 0000000000000001
0x000000000c06d840:   000000000c06d9d8 000000018002db42
0x000000000c06d850:   0000000000990ff0 0000000000990ff0
0x000000000c06d860:   0000000009d8a1f8 0000000061c58d94
0x000000000c06d870:   000000000b3537a0 0000000009f9ee40
0x000000000c06d880:   000000000b3540e0 000000000b3537a0
0x000000000c06d890:   0000000009d8a1f8 0000000061b73cd2
0x000000000c06d8a0:   0000000000990ff0 0000000009d8a1f8
0x000000000c06d8b0:   000000000b3537a0 000000000b3540e0
0x000000000c06d8c0:   0000000000000001 0000000000990ff0 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000001c48df09b)
0x00000001c48df07b:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000009d8a1f8 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000990ff0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000c06d7c8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000009d8a000
RSP=0x000000000c06d7d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000009d8a000
RBP=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000009f9ee40 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000018006eb38 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000008000 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000d73e75d8 is an oop
[Ljava.net.InetAddress; 
 - klass: 'java/net/InetAddress'[]
 - length: 2
R11=0x000000005eef0d50 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000000b35a180 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000c06d9d8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000009d8a000
R15=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000000bf70000,0x000000000c070000],  sp=0x000000000c06d7d0,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/net/InetAddress;+0
j  java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/net/InetAddress;+4
j  java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/net/InetAddress;)[Ljava/net/InetAddress;+51
j  java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/net/InetAddress;Z)[Ljava/net/InetAddress;+29
j  java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/net/InetAddress;)[Ljava/net/InetAddress;+383
j  java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/net/InetAddress;+2
j  java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/InetAddress;+1
j  java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I)V+15
j  org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.<clinit>()V+19
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.obtainLock(Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/internal/Lock;+0
j  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.connectTo(Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary;Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/ExtensionConnection;+1
j  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient()V+25
j  org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/CommandExecutor;Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)V+65
j  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary;Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile;Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)V+48
j  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary;Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile;Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)V+5
j  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+85
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+79
j  org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;+23
j  org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;+28
j  org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;+6
j  org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call()Lorg/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver;+8
j  org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run()V+51
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x0000000009d8a000 JavaThread "Session bda2f461-2645-43bb-9a80-4786c39faef1 processing inside browser" [_thread_in_native, id=8412, stack(0x000000000bf70000,0x000000000c070000)]
  0x0000000009e34000 JavaThread "DriverServlet Session Cleaner" [_thread_blocked, id=5128, stack(0x000000000b070000,0x000000000b170000)]
  0x00000000027d0800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=8856, stack(0x00000000026d0000,0x00000000027d0000)]
  0x000000000a025800 JavaThread "SocketListener0-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2520, stack(0x000000000be70000,0x000000000bf70000)]
  0x0000000009fa1000 JavaThread "SocketListener0-0" [_thread_blocked, id=288, stack(0x000000000bd70000,0x000000000be70000)]
  0x0000000009fa0800 JavaThread "Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=4444]" [_thread_in_native, id=8508, stack(0x000000000bc70000,0x000000000bd70000)]
  0x0000000009fbe800 JavaThread "SessionScavenger" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3648, stack(0x000000000bb70000,0x000000000bc70000)]
  0x0000000009fa2800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1724, stack(0x000000000ba70000,0x000000000bb70000)]
  0x0000000009c72800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4848, stack(0x000000000a050000,0x000000000a150000)]
  0x0000000008406800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4868, stack(0x0000000009b50000,0x0000000009c50000)]
  0x00000000083fc000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7364, stack(0x0000000009a50000,0x0000000009b50000)]
  0x00000000083f9800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5884, stack(0x0000000009950000,0x0000000009a50000)]
  0x0000000008404800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6356, stack(0x0000000009850000,0x0000000009950000)]
  0x0000000008403000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3560, stack(0x0000000009750000,0x0000000009850000)]
  0x00000000028c5800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7072, stack(0x0000000009650000,0x0000000009750000)]
  0x00000000028bd000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7560, stack(0x0000000009550000,0x0000000009650000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000083c7000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000009450000,0x0000000009550000] [id=5700]
  0x0000000009c84000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000000a150000,0x000000000a250000] [id=5820]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 21418K [0x00000000d5f00000, 0x00000000d8980000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 64% used [0x00000000d5f00000,0x00000000d73eaaf0,0x00000000d7f80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8480000,0x00000000d8480000,0x00000000d8980000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7f80000,0x00000000d7f80000,0x00000000d8480000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000081c00000, 0x0000000087180000, 0x00000000d5f00000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000081c00000,0x0000000081c00000,0x0000000087180000)
 Metaspace       used 9634K, capacity 9762K, committed 9984K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 1197K, capacity 1205K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000002c90000,0x0000000003090000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000002882000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005ef64040
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000003740000, 0x00000000056d0000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000056d0000, 0x0000000007660000)

Polling page: 0x00000000008a0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2302Kb max_used=2313Kb free=243457Kb
 bounds [0x000000000f010000, 0x000000000f280000, 0x000000001e010000]
 total_blobs=853 nmethods=533 adapters=233
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 133.578 Thread 0x00000000083f9800  529       4       java.lang.StringBuilder::append (8 bytes)
Event: 133.578 Thread 0x0000000008406800  528       1       java.lang.Boolean::booleanValue (5 bytes)
Event: 133.578 Thread 0x0000000008406800 nmethod 528 0x000000000f24ee50 code [0x000000000f24efa0, 0x000000000f24f0b0]
Event: 133.579 Thread 0x0000000008406800  530       3       java.io.StringWriter::write (10 bytes)
Event: 133.579 Thread 0x0000000008406800 nmethod 530 0x000000000f24f110 code [0x000000000f24f280, 0x000000000f24f688]
Event: 133.579 Thread 0x0000000008406800  531       3       com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive::isBoolean (8 bytes)
Event: 133.579 Thread 0x0000000008406800 nmethod 531 0x000000000f24f7d0 code [0x000000000f24f920, 0x000000000f24fb70]
Event: 133.579 Thread 0x0000000008406800  532       3       java.lang.Class::checkInitted (19 bytes)
Event: 133.579 Thread 0x0000000008406800 nmethod 532 0x000000000f24fc10 code [0x000000000f24fd80, 0x000000000f250048]
Event: 133.583 Thread 0x00000000083f9800 nmethod 529 0x000000000f253110 code [0x000000000f253260, 0x000000000f253638]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (2 events):
Event: 0.437 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000f1a9f64 method=java.lang.String.indexOf([CII[CIII)I @ 3
Event: 133.385 Thread 0x000000000a025800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000f1bc670 method=sun.misc.MetaIndex.mayContain(Ljava/lang/String;)Z @ 38

Internal exceptions (9 events):
Event: 0.070 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5f0d380) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\srŒÍÄÖü²?
Event: 0.070 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5f0d610) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jø'›hZÄ?
Event: 0.159 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d6141248) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.159 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d6141590) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.160 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61453a8) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.160 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d61456f0) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1382]
Event: 0.293 Thread 0x00000000027d0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError': org/apache/log4j/Category> (0x00000000d62a6568) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 199]
Event: 60.509 Thread 0x0000000009fa0800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Accept timed out> (0x00000000d68d6b28) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 120.518 Thread 0x0000000009fa0800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Accept timed out> (0x00000000d68d9288) thrown at [D:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u40\3098\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]

Events (10 events):
Event: 133.591 loading class org/openqa/selenium/internal/SocketLock
Event: 133.591 loading class org/openqa/selenium/internal/SocketLock done
Event: 133.591 loading class sun/net/InetAddressCachePolicy
Event: 133.591 loading class sun/net/InetAddressCachePolicy done
Event: 133.591 loading class sun/net/InetAddressCachePolicy$1
Event: 133.591 loading class sun/net/InetAddressCachePolicy$1 done
Event: 133.591 loading class sun/net/InetAddressCachePolicy$2
Event: 133.591 loading class sun/net/InetAddressCachePolicy$2 done
Event: 133.591 loading class java/net/InetAddress$CacheEntry
Event: 133.591 loading class java/net/InetAddress$CacheEntry done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7191f0000 - 0x00007ff719227000     C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
0x00007ffab5610000 - 0x00007ffab57bc000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffab2f80000 - 0x00007ffab30be000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffab2b70000 - 0x00007ffab2c85000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffab1270000 - 0x00007ffab12fe000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffaa4ad0000 - 0x00007ffaa4b23000     C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ffab5390000 - 0x00007ffab543a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffab24e0000 - 0x00007ffab250e000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffab51e0000 - 0x00007ffab5234000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffab2e00000 - 0x00007ffab2f77000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffab5040000 - 0x00007ffab51d4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffab3220000 - 0x00007ffab4738000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffab1f50000 - 0x00007ffab1f71000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffab4810000 - 0x00007ffab48ba000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffaa46d0000 - 0x00007ffaa46ee000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffab5240000 - 0x00007ffab5381000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffab4aa0000 - 0x00007ffab4af9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffab4b00000 - 0x00007ffab4d11000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ffab30c0000 - 0x00007ffab3211000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffab2760000 - 0x00007ffab2775000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffab0c20000 - 0x00007ffab0cd2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffab55d0000 - 0x00007ffab5606000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffab2c90000 - 0x00007ffab2de1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffab2710000 - 0x00007ffab2742000     C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll
0x00007ffab2690000 - 0x00007ffab269a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x000000000f000000 - 0x000000000f006000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\_etoured.dll
0x00007ffab0e90000 - 0x00007ffab0ec2000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrapx.dll
0x00007ffab48c0000 - 0x00007ffab4a9a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ffab2830000 - 0x00007ffab287f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x00007ffab0df0000 - 0x00007ffab0e12000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll
0x00007ffab0570000 - 0x00007ffab07eb000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17415_none_6240486fecbd8abb\COMCTL32.dll
0x0000000061bf0000 - 0x0000000061cc2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005e760000 - 0x000000005efe3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffaa4690000 - 0x00007ffaa4699000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffaaf6d0000 - 0x00007ffaaf6f2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffab5030000 - 0x00007ffab5037000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffab4fd0000 - 0x00007ffab502a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffaaf4e0000 - 0x00007ffaaf50a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffab5440000 - 0x00007ffab5449000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffab14c0000 - 0x00007ffab14e8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x0000000061be0000 - 0x0000000061bef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000061bb0000 - 0x0000000061bd9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\java.dll
0x0000000061b90000 - 0x0000000061ba6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\zip.dll
0x0000000061b70000 - 0x0000000061b8a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\net.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180078000     C:\Windows\system32\ASProxy64.dll
0x00007ffab1ef0000 - 0x00007ffab1f49000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll
0x00007ffab1760000 - 0x00007ffab178a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffab4d20000 - 0x00007ffab4de1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffab1750000 - 0x00007ffab175a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
0x00007ffab1510000 - 0x00007ffab151b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffab2580000 - 0x00007ffab258b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x00007ffab2510000 - 0x00007ffab2573000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffab1340000 - 0x00007ffab1469000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffaac520000 - 0x00007ffaac60e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Stardock\Start8\Start8_64.dll
0x00007ffaad1e0000 - 0x00007ffaad35f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
0x00007ffab5450000 - 0x00007ffab5506000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ffab20b0000 - 0x00007ffab20d0000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ffab1ba0000 - 0x00007ffab1bd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ffab21d0000 - 0x00007ffab21f6000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffab25f0000 - 0x00007ffab2689000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
0x00007ffaaba30000 - 0x00007ffaaba46000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ffaabc40000 - 0x00007ffaabc5a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x0000000061b50000 - 0x0000000061b61000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin\nio.dll
0x00007ffab1cf0000 - 0x00007ffab1d94000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00007ffaa60d0000 - 0x00007ffaa60da000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00007ffaabb10000 - 0x00007ffaabb7b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x00007ffaa3960000 - 0x00007ffaa3aea000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
java_command: selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
java_class_path (initial): selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Python27\python;C:\Users\Don Carlos\AppData\Roaming\npm
USERNAME=Don Carlos
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.17415)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8271684k(5556304k free), swap 18757444k(15574932k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_40-b26), built on Mar  7 2015 13:51:59 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu Apr 02 10:10:48 2015
elapsed time: 133 seconds (0d 0h 2m 13s)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds related to *compatibility issues* between selenium 2.44 (which you are using) and firefox >35. **Upgrade selenium to 2.45**:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Or, *downgrade firefox to 34.0.5*.

See also:

- [Issue 8399: Firefox 36 breaks WebDriver 2.44.0](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8399)
- [Heads up: Protractor is not working with Firefox 35/36](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1734)

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome & phantomJS (also when upgraded to 2.45)

Comment: @Jelle thanks, and it the upgrade made no difference in case of firefox too?